# Strings of characters using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm trying to write a function which changes letters into two asterisks (`*`) using pointers.

For example:

> Input: `hello12345good++//--ok`
>
> Output: `**********123456********++//--****`

I've writen one that changes letters into two of the same letters, but couldn't write the same for `*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int points_converter(char str[])
{
    char *s, *s1;
    int f = 0;

    for (s = str; *s; s++)
    {
        if(isalpha(*s))
        {
            f = 1;
            s1 = s;
            s = s + strlen(s);
            while(s != s1 - 1)
                *(s+1) = *(s--);
            s = s + 2;
        }
    }
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    char str[81];
    int f;
    puts("Input string:");
    while (strlen(gets(str)) >= 81);

    f = points_converter(str);
    if (f == 0)
    {
        puts("No latin letters in string.");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("New string: ");
        puts(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop will not save yourself from the badness of `gets`. Once the call to `strlen` is made the function will already have written out of bounds. Don't use `gets`, plain and simple. Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: As for your problem, the expression `s = s + strlen(s)` will make `s` point to the location of the string terminator. So when you do `*(s + 1)` (which is exactly equal to `s[1]`) you might be outside the string.

Comment: Are you making this change in-place? Are you ensuring that your allocated memory has sufficient space?

Comment: For safety, `points_converter()` should have a second argument that gives the length of memory allocated to the array.

Comment: `>= 81` --> `> 40`

Answer (score 3):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool points_converter(char str[]){
    bool f = false;
    char *temp = malloc(strlen(str)*2+1);
    char *s = str, *d = temp;

    if(!temp){
        perror("malloc:");
        return f;//no change
    }    
    for (; *s; s++){
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)*s)){
            f = true;
            *d++ = '*';
            *d++ = '*';
        } else {
            *d++ = *s;
        }
    }
    *d = 0;
    strcpy(str, temp);//`str` must have enough spaces.
    free(temp);
    return f;
}

#define MAX_LENGTH 40

int main(void){
    char str[MAX_LENGTH * 2 + 1];

    while(true){
        puts("Input string:");
        fgets(str, MAX_LENGTH+1+1, stdin);//+1:newline, +1:NUL. Use fgets instead of gets
        char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
        if(p){
            *p = '\0';//chomp newline
            break;
        } else {
            while (getchar() != '\n');//Input too long, clear input
        }
    }

    if (points_converter(str)) {
        puts("New string: ");
        puts(str);
    } else {
        puts("No latin letters in string.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be tempting to use a static array in `points_converter` since `MAX_LENGTH` is a constant, but dynamic allocation makes it reusable.

Comment: Curious: Why "No latin letters in string." rather than "No letters in string.".  Does not `isalpha()` report true for all letters, latin or not?

Comment: I try to be the same behavior as the original.

Answer (score -1):

how about:

```
static const int MAXINPUTLEN=81;

int points_converter(const char* input, char *output) 
{ 
   int count = 0; // initialize counter to zero   
   while (*input) { // while input is not pointing to zero
     if (isalpha(*input)) { // if input is pointing to alpha
       output[0] = '*'; // replace first byte pointed to by output with '*'
       output[1] = '*'; // replace 2nd byte pointed to by output with '*'
       output += 2; // increment output by 2
       count++; // increment counter
     } else { 
       *output = *input; // copy non-alpha to output
       output++; // increment output by one
     }
     input++; // increment input pointer by one
   }
   *output = 0; // terminate output with zero byte
   return count; // return count
}

int main()
{
   char input[MAXINPUTLEN + 1];
   char output[2 * MAXINPUTLEN + 1];
   gets(input); // not checking for input overflow!
   points_converter(input, output);
}
```

Comment: thank you! how it will be if I need 2 asterisks instead of 1?
for example: 
     **hello** -->   **********

Comment: care to comment on the downvote (='not useful') as I might learn something from it?